# A common type cast for lambda's and functions to reference later

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Why is it the second example does not work? Is there a way I could get the second example to work while still type casting the lambda or function into a medium to reference later?

```
// Types I'm using
typedef void (*ANY_FUNC)(...);
typedef void (*VOID_FUNC)();
```

**This works**

```
void call_void( VOID_FUNC func) {
    ((ANY_FUNC)func)();
};

// ...

call_void([]() { /* do something */ });
```

**This doesn't**

```
template <typename fn>
void call_any( fn func ) {
    ((ANY_FUNC)func)();
};

// ...

call_any([]() { /* do something */ });
```

Please ignore the fact that you would never need to use the second example how it is now. It's only for demonstration (relative code).

*Both examples work with function pointers instead of lambdas.*

Comment: As an aside: Avoid using C style casts, because they can work even when they should not.  Instead, do `ANY_FUNC f = func; f();` so that the cast (if it occurs and works) is implicit without forcing anything.  This has zero overhead at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As long as you are declaring a template you can just use the incoming function object](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=sfinae) directly. Also, you should declare your function argument as a reference not as by value:

```
template <typename fn>
void call_any(fn&& func) {
    func();
};
```

And if you want to call a function with arguments you can do:

```
template <typename fn, typename... Args>
void call_any_many(fn&& func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

Usage example:

```
int main ()
{
    call_void([]() { std::cout << "Hello, void World!" << std::endl; });
    call_any([]() { std::cout << "Hello, any World!" << std::endl; });
    call_any_many([](int x) { std::cout << "Hello, any many World-" << x << "!" << std::endl; }, 1234);

    return 0;
}
```

But if your intention is to store some function pointers and not to call them directly, I suggest using `std::function` from `<functional>` header. You can see some information and example from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main ()
{
    std::function<void()> anyf = []() { std::cout << "Hello, any World!" << std::endl; };
    std::function<void(int)> intf = [](int x) { std::cout << "Hello, any many World-" << x << "!" << std::endl; };

    anyf();
    intf(1234);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of them *really* works, except perhaps by chance on some compilers.

The difference with a lambda is that it is convertible to a function pointer, but it isn't one. The templated version will notice this difference, and `fn` is not deduced as `VOID_FUNC`.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are implicitly convertible to function pointers (but only if they don't capture anything), so just change call_any's parameter to a function pointer:

```
void call_any(ANY_FUNC func)
{
    (*func)();
}
```

You would need to call it with a lambda of the appropriate type:

```
call_any([](...) { /* ... */ });
```

But variable-length argument lists (aka varargs) are bad because they are as non-type-safe as you can get. Same with function pointers: they are non-object-oriented. You should think of an alternative mechanism, perhaps involving variadic templates and polymorphism (virtual methods)

Answer (score 0):

The first is converting a lambda to a function pointer with corresponding argument and return types, then casting that to a vararg function, whereas the second is attempting to convert a lambda directly to a vararg function (i.e., a function without corresponding argument types).

The two conversions in the first example are allowed*, but the single conversion in the second is not.

*** Note that the cast notation you use to convert between function pointer types ends up working like `reinterpret_cast` which states: "A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined." And therefore the first example code has undefined behavior.